# Sometimes cannot launch an application programmatically on jailbroken device

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, launching-application, springboard

```
 NSInteger error = SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier((CFStringRef)bundleID, NO);
 NSLog(@"launching [%@] error: [%d]", bundleName, error);
 if (error) {
   CFStringRef errorStr = SBSApplicationLaunchingErrorString(error);
   DLog(@"launching %@ error to string [%@]", bundleName, (NSString *)errorStr);
   CFRelease(errorStr);
 }
```

I use the above code to launch my second application from my first application, mostly it can launch successfully. However, **SOMETIMES** it fails to launch. I see this error on syslog

> > launching [myFirstApp] error: [7]
> >
> > launching myFirstApp error to string [application not found]

How can I always launch the application?

Note that my first application is running as a daemon

Comment: You've given your daemon the `com.apple.springboard.launchapplications` entitlement?

Comment: I have already added com.apple.springboard.launchapplications entitlement to the daemon